# I'm new to CSS, I'm interested in how to choose the first list from an html document to style if I don't have a div or class in either

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS, I'm interested in how to choose the first sheet from an html document to style if I don't have a div or class in either.
First list -

- Stavka liste - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, ea eum laudantium dolorum, animi quae commodi porro fugiat, sequi odit at voluptas voluptate ducimus reiciendis expedita sint. Minima, quae, pariatur.
- Stavka liste - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa accusamus dolor porro explicabo cum at, rem modi eos reiciendis unde, tempora maxime nobis veritatis laborum ea doloremque in! Harum, sit.
- Stavka liste - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro dignissimos quae optio laboriosam nostrum saepe inventore dolorem explicabo nihil magni tempora perferendis enim impedit at officiis consectetur ullam illum, iure.
- Stavka liste - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, earum laborum molestias, soluta ullam ut veniam accusantium voluptatum nihil molestiae aperiam inventore quisquam ipsa repudiandae quasi, debitis, ex laudantium eaque.

Second list -

- Stavka

  1. Podstavka
  2. Podstavka
  3. Podstavka
- Nova stavka

  1. Nova podstavka
  2. Nova podstavka
  3. Nova podstavka
  4. Nova podstavka

I want to target just one without putting class or div to html file.

I tried to do nth child etc functions but its change both lists

Comment: It should be more clear for us to answer if you include the example in an HTML code. If your text has no tags at all, then it should have for countless reasons. `<html><body>Some text</body></html>` is not a good practice at all.

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure? and exactly what do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way..i used ul:first-of-type and ul:last-of-type. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) pseudo class :

```css
ul:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
First list
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>

Second list
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```